# Visual Studio Not Finding tsconfig.json

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have an existing web project (loaded in Visual Studio via open existing website and saved with a .sln solution.  I want to integrate an angular2 silo into part of the site.  My site structure is:

```
| ... site folders ...
| myAngularApps
   | application1
      | app - main application files
      | node_modules
      | typings
      | package.json
      | tsconfig.json
      | systemjs.config.js
| ... site folders ...
web.config, etc.
```

My tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "watch": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "files": [],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build" 
  ] 
}
```

Visual studio recognises package.json (and updates node_modules) accordingly.  However, it does not recognise tsconfig.json.

If I set compile on save, my typescript files are compiled to js.  However, by not recognising tsconfig.json, none of the options are implemented (souremap, emitDecoratorMetadata, etc).  I can compile the files outside of Visual Studio using tsc, but this is a continuing pain.

How can I get Visual Studio to recognise my tsconfig.json file?

Comment: This has been problematic for awhile. I don't remember everything I had to do anymore but some of it was - need a tsconfig.json at the ROOT folder. Visual Studio needs to be using typescript version > 1.8 I believe, just install 2.0 but getting visual studio to actually use the updated version was harder then it should be.... to be continued.

Comment: Assuming all of that is ok you will also need to go into tools->options and under text editor-> typescript->projects make sure that compile and save->Automatically compile typescript files which are not part of the project is turned off to prevent issues where it tries to compile npm/bower packages that it shouldn't be which causes issues.

Comment: You know you are at least on the right path once you get it to the point where if you right click the project->Properties and the typescript tab is greyed out and has "One or more tsconfig.json files detected" at the top of the tab screen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I decided to start the compiler in watch mode as an external command, and this seems to do the job.